# rsync files/folders from a list in an input file and exclude from an exclude file

Tags: linux, include, rsync

I have two files with a list of folders. I want to sync the folders, with relative paths, to the destination excluding those from the exclude file.

```
$ cat include.txt
/home/user
/etc
/data/app
/boot

$ cat exclude.txt
/data/app/temp
/etc/aide
```

I have tried using `--include-from` and `--files-from` but can't seem to figure out it.

This seems to sync the folders, but not the files:

```
rsync -av --files-from=include.txt / /destination
```

Ultimately I want to sync to `/destination` and have the folder structure look like:

```
/destination/home/user
/destination/home/user/...
/destination/etc
/destination/etc/...
/destination/data/app
/destination/data/app/...
/destination/boot
/destination/boot/...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `-r` and `--exclude-from` options and You should be good to go:

```
rsync -av -r --files-from=./include.txt --exclude-from=./exclude.txt / /destination/
```

Comment: I am going to hit myself. How could I miss that `--files-from` removes recursion so you have to add it back. I am so dumb. Thank you!

Comment: Glad that helped. This is quite non-straightforward in rsync, I also broke my theeth on this one.